# How to integrate this Gaussian like equation: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x^2}}{z-x}dx, z \in \mathbb{C}$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, gaussian-integral

Could anyone show me how to perform this integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x^2}}{z-x}dx, z \in \mathbb{C}$$
Thanks.
The following is what I have tried.

Set $z = iz^\prime$, also make the substitution $v = iz^\prime - x$, then
$$-e^{z^{\prime 2}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-v^2+2ivz^\prime}}{v}dv.$$
Then we can set $f(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-v^2+2ivz}}{v}dv$, so
$$f^\prime(z) = 2i\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{e^{-v^2+2ivz}}dv
=2ie^{-z^2}.$$
Also we have $f(0) = 0$. Then 
$$f(z) = \int_0^z f^\prime(z)dz=i\int_{-z}^z e^{-t^2}dt=i\mathrm{erf}(z).$$
So the final result should be like 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x^2}}{z-x}dx = -ie^{-z^2}\mathrm{erf}(-iz).$$
But the answer is $e^{z^2}(1-\mathrm{erf}(z))$. It seems the answer is wrong, since when $z=0$, the value should be 0 because the integrand is an odd function. But then I tried the wollfram alpha, The result is
[image]

The result is in accordance with the answer. I know that there are some steps which are not rigid, could someone give me the full derivation of this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Change of variables and then Gamma, Beta functions stuffs?

Comment: @Dando18, I got something like erf(z), but the answer is 1- erf(z). It seems that the answer is wrong(since z=0), But then i tried wolfram alpha with z=3j, the result seems in accordance with the answer.

Comment: @Jack, I have tried that, sorry for not mentioning that in the qurstion.

Comment: Edit in your attempts into the question and you're more likely to receive help

Comment: $e^{-z^2} \left(\pi  \text{erfi}(z)-\log \left(-\frac{1}{z}\right)-\log (z)\right)$

Comment: @Raffaele, could you please post a more detailed version of the deriavation? Thanks.

Comment: "*when $z = 0$, the value should be $0$ because the integrand is an odd function*". **NO!** The integral does not converge for the same reason $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{x} dx$ does not converge. In fact, your integral will not converge for any real $z$.

Comment: @SteamyRoot Very true.  I suppose one could regularize it as either:$$\lim_{y\to0^+}\int_{\mathbb R}\frac{e^{-x^2}}{z+iy-x}~\mathrm dx$$Or take the limit from below.  (which btw won't end up as zero)

Comment: @SteamyRoot, Yes, I have realized this but I am not familiar with complex analysis.

Comment: @yangcs11 Then for what reason are you attempting this question?

Comment: @Simply, I encounter this integral in a paper which deals with inhomogeneous broadening of atom ensemble in a cavity.

Comment: @Dando18 Btw, seems the attempts have been added (yay!)

Comment: Well, I don't have time to actually work this out, but from Cauchy's integral formula or residue stuff, you get $-e^{-z^2} = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_\gamma \frac{e^{-w^2}}{z-w}dw$ with $\gamma$ a semicircle of radius $R > |z|$ and centre $0$. Splitting this contour integral in two parts (the real line and the circular part), you should be able to get there, I think.

Comment: for $z\in R$ you should interpret  the integral in a principal value sense. i think a closed form is still possible in this case

Comment: the master himself already told us how to solve this integral:
http://residuetheorem.com/2015/08/07/cauchy-principal-value/

Comment: @SteamyRoot nope, the integral diverges at the arc of the contour

Comment: @Steamy, I looked up the Cauchy integral, the contour should be two arcs, otherwise the contribution of the arcs will not be zero( actually, it will diverge as \at tired suggested) but thanks a lot for pointing out the direction.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $z\not\in\mathbb{R}$, the given integral equals

$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{2z}{z^2-x^2}e^{-x^2}\,dx \stackrel{x\mapsto\sqrt{u}}{=}z\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-u}}{\sqrt{u}(z^2-u)}\,du $$
that just depends on the [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{u}(z^2-u)}$,  that can be computed from the Laplace transform of $\frac{2}{z}\text{arctanh}\left(\frac{\sqrt{u}}{z}\right)$ or simply from the Laplace transform of $\text{arctanh}(\sqrt{u})$.

Comment: i would try differentiation under the integral sign in your first integral. We get an ODE which should be straightforward to solve using variation of parameters

Comment: @tired: that works, for sure.

Comment: But how to perform the Laplace transform of the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{u}(z^2-u^2)}$ ?

Comment: I tried to find it but not succeeded. It seems we have to use here https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=inverse+laplace+transform&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22InverseLaplaceTransformCalculator%22%2C+%22transformfunction%22%7D+-%3E%22%0C1%2F%28%5Csqrt%28s%29%28a%5E2-s%5E2%29%29%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22InverseLaplaceTransformCalculator%22%2C+%22variable1%22%7D+-%3E%22s%22&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C+%22inverse+laplace+transform%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22Calculator%22%2C+%22dflt%22%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22InverseLaplaceTransformCalculator%22%2C+%22variable2%22%7D+-%3E%22t%22